# Any good tutorial/sample Asynchronous Socket with thread pool code and allow sending or receiving more than one time

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, asynchronous

Any good tutorial/sample Asynchronous Socket with thread pool code and allow sending or receiving more than one time?

I tried Microsoft sample Asynchronous server sample and Asynchronous client sample  , it only allow receiving or sending once and then it end the session.[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) i have no idea how to allow receiving or sending data more than once.

what i want to do is a server & client verify process, that using signature and AES, to verify the client is really the real client and the server is the real server.

This is the following verify step process i plan to do

1. Client will generate a hash and send to the server.
2. The server will receive the hash and encrypt his private key and send the encrypted hash & the public key back tot the client.
3. The client receives the server's public key and the encrypted hash and decrypt the encrypted hash with the server's public key.
4. The client will compare the decrypted hash with the hash that the client sent, it is the same, if the result is equal, then the client will encrypt the AES key & Iv using the server's public key and then send to the server.
5. When the server received the encrypted AES key & IV, the server will decrypt it with his private key and then use the AES key & IV to encrypt the hash and then send it to the client.
6. The client revived the encrypted hash and use the AES key & IV to decrypt and compar eit again.

Comment: I hope this helps: https://github.com/vtortola/AynchronousTCPListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the protocol you are describing you can implement yourself but in terms of sending and receiving data from a socket, there is an [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/12/15/10248293.aspx) from Stephen Toub that creates a `SocketAwaitable` that allows to easily send/receive data asynchronously.

From the article you would use it like this:

```
static async Task ReadAsync(Socket s) 
{ 
    // Reusable SocketAsyncEventArgs and awaitable wrapper 
    var args = new SocketAsyncEventArgs(); 
    args.SetBuffer(new byte[0x1000], 0, 0x1000); 
    var awaitable = new SocketAwaitable(args);

    // Do processing, continually receiving from the socket 
    while (true) 
    { 
        await s.ReceiveAsync(awaitable); 
        int bytesRead = args.BytesTransferred; 
        if (bytesRead <= 0) break;

        /* Process bytes read here */
    } 
}
```

Comment: is that Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP)? is need framework 4.5, anyway thank to pointing it out, as i am new on this and i did know there is something called Asynchronous Programming Patterns.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156548(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Asynchronous Programming Model and Event-based Asynchronous Pattern are older ways of doing asynchronous development. The newer ways involve using the Task Parallel Library and using the Task-based Asynchronous Pattern  (TAP). The above example uses TAP